# How to keep track of value using a variable, without resetting said variable on recursive calls, without using global variable, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, recursion, global-variables, global

Basically I have a recursive function to calculate space in certain structures. I want to keep track of 'space' throughout the recursion without the space value resetting on each call. I was previously using a 'space' variable declared outside the function, but it's causing me issues. Is this possible without using a global variable? How?

Current code:

```
var space = 0;
  
var fill = function(arr) {
    
    if(arr.length < 1) {
        return space;
    }

    for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        ... various conditions and arr manipulation ...
        space+=1
    }

    return fill(arr)
}
```

example input:

```
fill([2,4,0,9])
```

Comment: You should use a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a second parameter for the counting.

```
var fill = function(array, space = 0) {
    if (array.length < 1) return space;

    // some code with
    space++;

    return fill(array, space);
};
```

Comment: Why wrap the value in  an object? Now you still have only one single global instance with a single property value.

Comment: I use this technique regularly, but we should not ignore its downside.  `arrayOfArrays .map (fill)` will not do what you might expect, because `map` supplies `fill` with a second parameter, the index.  Sometimes it's just cleaner to make this a private function and have a wrapper function with the public API you want.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, as i see the question, the function is not ment fto be used as callback for `Array#map`. if so, the second parameter is always given and contradict a dynamic use.

Comment: But then you would have to document such restrictions on its usage, probably even for yourself a few weeks later.  I've caused myself problems with this in a matter of minutes.  The problem is that this is a function of arity `1` and documentation is likely to ignore the second parameter altogether as an implementation detail.  It's not that this technique is wrong, only that it comes with some non-obvious restrictions.  And although I do still use it often enough, I've been bitten by it more than once.